# unable to assign Json string of array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

The GetAllCountries retrieve list of countries from controller action(MVC).I am unable to assign the countries to select element( as shown in the mark up). On the other hand if I assign values as `model.countries = ["India","USA"];` it worked. How do I assign the return values?

> ```
> var initialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));
>
>
>     function StudentViewModel() {
>         var self = this;
>         self.students = ko.observableArray([]);
>         self.countries =[];
>         self.editingItem = ko.observable();
>         self.isItemEditing = function(itemToTest) {
>             return itemToTest == self.editingItem();
>         };
>     };
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         var url = '/GridDemo/GetAllCountries';
>         $.ajax({ url: url, success: dataRetrieved, type: 'POST', dataType: 'json' });
>         var model = new StudentViewModel();
>         //model.countries = ["India","USA"];
>         function dataRetrieved(data) {
>             var strCountry = [];
>             for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
>                 strCountry.push(data[i]);
>             }
>             //alert(strCountry);
>            model.countries = strCountry;
>
>         }
>        // alert(initialData.country);
>         //model.countries = initialData.Countries;
>         model.students(initialData);
>         ko.applyBindings(model);   
>
>     });
> ```

HTML :

```
 <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.countries, value: 
  Country, visible: $root.isItemEditing($data)"></select>
 <label data-bind="text: Country, visible: !$root.isItemEditing($data)" />
```

When I pop up the json result I got exactly: India,America,Nepal.

Action in the controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetAllCountries()
        {
            var countries = new[] { "India", "America", "Nepal" };
            return Json(countries, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: what does the url url = '/GridDemo/GetAllCountries'; return. I cant see the code. Make Sure it return valid json

Comment: Please check the above changes.

Comment: But Anyway i was able to parse the result and push into array. Still the assignment of the array doesn't work (please see above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `countries` also an `ko.observableArray`

```
function StudentViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.students = ko.observableArray();
        self.countries = ko.observableArray();
        self.editingItem = ko.observable();
        self.isItemEditing = function(itemToTest) {
            return itemToTest == self.editingItem();
        };
    };
```

And in your `dataRetrieved` you need to assign the `strCountry` to the  `model.countries`:

```
function dataRetrieved(data) {
    var strCountry = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        strCountry.push(data[i]);
    }
    model.countries(strCountry);
}
```

Or you can directly `push` into your observable array ([documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating_an_observablearray)):

```
function dataRetrieved(data) {
    model.countries.removeAll();
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        model.countries.push(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried both but it didn't work. I got error: removeAll is not a function

Comment: @arjun then please a sample response `data` what you get in the `dataRetrieved` function!

Comment: You should also check your browser's javascript console looking for errors!

Comment: Could you please see the changes above

Comment: Please check again your console for errors. If you correctly receives an array in dataRetrived then pusgin into an observable array should work. See in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AUmqy/